# Why does increasing my number of levels in Random Factor ANOVA increase my statistical power?

Tags: anova, spss, statistical-power, degrees-of-freedom

In my Fixed Factor ANOVA I have 60 participants split evenly with two IVs with two levels in each IV (DF:1x1x1=1):

IV1: Level 1: 15

IV1: Level 2: 15

IV2: Level 1: 15

IV2: Level 2: 15

But in my second trial, IV3 is Fixed and IV4 is Random. So I have (DF:1x1x2=2):

IV3: Level 1: 15

IV3: Level 2: 15

IV4: Level 1: 10

IV4: Level 2: 10

IV4: Level 3: 10

Because I know that 10 is my minimum group size (but I don't understand why) and that I need to increase my levels to increase my degrees of freedom to account for more randomness in my data (?) but how does this affect my power? I don't know how to check this in SPSS without any data.